# Is there a way to quickly convert degrees to radians in windows calculator?

Tags: windows, calculator

Is there a way to quickly convert radians to degrees and back in windows calculator without using the formula:

```
radians = degrees * Math.PI/180
```

(something similar to converting between number base by just clicking on DEC/HEX radio  buttons).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Upgrade to Windows 7.[image]

Comment: *Finally*, a compelling reason to upgrade. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just put it into google, and google can convert it for you.  Google calculator works from the search prompt, and can convert pretty much any unit to any other unit.

Try a "search" for:

`3.7 radians in degrees`

or

`107.8 degrees in radians`

[It can do an awful lot more too.](http://www.google.com/help/calculator.html)

Comment: How does this even remotely relate to the question?

Comment: It's a way to convert degrees to radians without any special software.

Comment: A calc isn't that "special", methinks. The man asked how to do it in calc; you answer "google". Therefore my question. Nwm.

Comment: Well instead of saying "no" with no further info, I offered an alternative.  That's the spirit of this site, offering assistance.

Comment: The question was how to convert it without using the formula; this accomplishes that task quickly and easily. The question did not say that it *must* be with the Windows calculator.

Answer (score 2):

For answers in *-π* to *+π*, you can use the following trick to covert from Rad to Deg:

- Select the *Radians* radio button, enter your radian value and hit <kbd>Sin</kbd>
- Select the *Degrees* radio button and hit <kbd>Inv</kbd>, then <kbd>Sin</kbd>

The reverse also works for Deg to Rad.

Comment: in Windows 10 if you resize the calculator window to make it bigger then the `sin⁻¹` button will be available directly without pressing the `Inv` button

Answer (score 0):

Not without doing the multiplication yourself (you could store the factor in the memory).

You may like [Calc98](http://www.calculator.org/download.aspx). Using it, you:

- press the Unit button
- select angle in the Property field
- select deg in the From field
- select radians in the to field
- click OK
- enter a number and click the cnv> button, repeat this step for additional conversions

[image: Calc98]

Answer (score 0):

To convert degrees to radians, copy the following text `*p/180=` then in Calculator you can press Ctrl+V to convert. For example,

45 Ctrl+V `0.78539816339744830961566084581988`
90 Ctrl+V `1.5707963267948966192313216916398`
180 Ctrl+V `3.1415926535897932384626433832795`
360 Ctrl+V `6.283185307179586476925286766559`

To convert radians to degrees, copy the following text `*180/p=` then in Calculator you can press Ctrl+V to convert. For example,

1 Ctrl+V `57.295779513082320876798154814105`
2 Ctrl+V `114.59155902616464175359630962821`
3.14 Ctrl+V `179.90874767107848755314620611629`

Be aware that when you copy something, the conversion function will be lost. With that in mind, these pasteable conversion functions might be useful if you have several conversions to make, but might be less useful for multi-step calcuations that you want to copy and paste results from.

Comment: That’s still using the formula, which the OP specifically asked about avoiding. Besides, typing it directly would be much easier than copy-pasting.

Comment: you can use a macro to type that sequence though, no need to copy and paste